# How can I get value from the API JSON response object and assign it to constant in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, object, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch the prices from coingecko API it's returning object json response how can I get that response value and assign it to const **rate** directly to my calculation here the below code I'm try to achieve

```
fetch(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=${give}&vs_currencies=${get}`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data.responseText)
    const rate = data.responseText;
    rateE1.innerText = `1 ${give} = ${rate} ${get}`

    get_qty_enter.value = (give_qty_enter.value * rate).toFixed(5);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

What error are you getting?

You can process the data according to the field names in the incoming reply;

```
//For example
var rate = data.responseText;
console.log(rate.currency, rate.amount);
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'currency')

Answer (score 1):

You should cultivate reading the documentation while you are exploring the new tech.

here i wrote an example for doge to usd.

HTML

```
Amount Of Coins <br>
    <input type="text" id="give_qty_enter" placeholder="give" /><br><br><br>

    Total USD for Coins <br>
    <input type="text" id="get_qty_enter" placeholder="get" />

    <button id="rateBtn">Change</button>

    <h1 id="rateE1"></h1>
```

JS

```
    let give = "1doge";
    let get = "usd";
    let rateE1 = document.getElementById("rateE1");
    let give_qty_enter = document.getElementById("give_qty_enter");
    let get_qty_enter = document.getElementById("get_qty_enter");
    let rateBtn = document.getElementById("rateBtn");

    rateBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        fetch(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=${give}&vs_currencies=${get}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                const rate = data["1doge"].usd;
                rateE1.innerText = `1 ${give.split("1")[1]} = ${rate} ${get}`

                get_qty_enter.value = (give_qty_enter.value * rate).toFixed(5);
            })
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
    });
```

Read these two sections carefully on this link. 
https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/documentation

**/simple/price** 
**/simple/supported_vs_currencies**
**/coins/list**

Comment: The value of ${give} & ${get} is assigned dynamically from options dropdown and i'm trying to assigning that fetched price to the const rate like this: const rate = data[{give}][{get}]; but it showing TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '#<Object>')

Comment: Jeez. You still don't get it.   Try this format => const rate = data[`${give}`][`${get}`];

Comment: same as red underlined syntax error

Comment: Please guide me About this issues I will greatly appreciate this response.

Comment: above code contains a type error ow resolve and I'm unable to get that